# How to import the Kendo UI typings into a TypeScript module

Tags: typescript, kendo-ui

I work with Kendo UI for React, using TypeScript. I am trying to import the Kendo UI typings for TypeScript using a "typeof import".

Following the instructions at
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/third-party/typescript
I installed the kendo-ui typings:

```
npm install --save @types/kendo-ui
```

I added the line

```
declare var Grid: typeof import("kendo-ui");
```

to my .tsx file.

However, this gives me the error message

```
@types/kendo-ui/index.d.ts is not a module
```

for the "import("kendo-ui")" bit.

Looking at that file in the node_modules directory, this indeed does not have imports or exports.

How can I import the Kendo-UI TypeScript types into my .tsx module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have `@types/kendo-ui` installed and you haven't overridden the `types` compiler option, the TypeScript compiler should load the Kendo UI global declarations automatically.  It looks like the grid class you are looking for is named `kendo.ui.Grid`, so you could write:

```
declare var Grid: kendo.ui.Grid;
```